# Django select distinct only has related objects with specified foreign key id

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to list regions that has related objects with specified category id.

The query I wrote does that for all categories:

```
models.Fedsubj.objects.filter(articles__isnull=False).distinct()
```

But how do I specify category (`id_section`)?

### Models

```
class Fedsubj(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fesname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fessort = models.IntegerField()
    fescont = models.TextField()


class SectionArt(MPTTModel):
    id_section = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_sec = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)


class Articles(models.Model):
    id_art = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_art = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    id_section = TreeForeignKey(SectionArt, db_column='id_section')
    fesid = models.ForeignKey(Fedsubj, db_column='fesid')
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want the distinction property to be checked on some particular attribute of the row like id_section.?

Comment: I mean I want to filter my `Fedsubj` (regions), so I will get a list of `Fedsubj`, that has articles of some `section_id` (category) e.g. `5`

Comment: Show us Fedsubj definition.

Comment: Oh, so you want only those Fedsubj, that has articles of section_id s1, s2, s3, or s4 i.e., the articles' section should belong to a particular list or something?

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi it will be one particular selectable `section_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
models.Fedsubj.objects.filter(articles__isnull=False, articles__id_section=some_sectionart_instance).distinct()
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'articles_set' into field. Choices are: articles, cities, fescont, fesname, fessort, id`. I also tried `articles__set__id_section=category`, but got `FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: set`

Comment: This is strange. Try `articles__id_section` instead of `articles_set__id_section`.

Comment: Yay! It worked. Edit your answer and I will accept it.